# Help with a differentiation question.

Tags: calculus, physics

I have a question with deriving velocity from the following SUVAT equation. Can i get some help please.

The question:

The equation for distance, s (m), traveled in time t (s) by an object starting with initial velocity u (ms-1) and uniform acceleration a (ms-2) is..

$$s = ut + ½ at^2$$

i) differentiate the equation to find the function for velocity (v =ds/dt)

Step by step workout would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: don't you know how to differentiate?

Comment: I started studying calculus not so long ago

Comment: That's okay, differentiating polynomials is easy. See [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-differentiation-1-new/ab-2-6b/v/differentiating-polynomials-example) short video on khan academy

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have constants $u$, and $a$ and your variables are $t$ and $s$

You want to differentiate $$ ut+(1/2) at^2$$

Derivative of $ut$ is $u$ and derivative of $ t^2$ is $2t$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you. I've got it.